# not able to move to element with div tag in xpath in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am having xpath like this "//div[contains(@id, 'smothing')]//tr[@class='something']/th[1]/a

I am not able to move to element using actions moveToElement() method, but is clicking when I manually move to the element.

Please help how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Can u please share error trace /

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: Share your code ! So we can help u

Comment: You should share your code.

Comment: waitop.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'smothing')]//tr[@class='something']/th[1]/a"));
  WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'smothing')]//tr[@class='something']/th[1]/a"));
  String Opp = ele.getText();
  System.out.println(Opp);
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  act.moveToElement(ele);
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
  act.perform();

Comment: Why u are using ` driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`  here?

Comment: First I didnot used, but later given a try. But it didnot worked

Comment: action.moveToElement(element).build().perform(); try this line of code

Answer (score 0):

if you are clicking element using javascript as you mentioned in you code, you don't really need to move to (Scroll to) your element.

```
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

I am also against using javascript click, until there is no way you can't click using native events.

if `MoveToElement` is not working, you could use javascript to move to element and then click using native event (webdriver click)

```
void scrollTo(WebElement element){
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```

Comment: I am facing same probelm, My code is like below executor.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele);
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);

Comment: and what is happening. are you not able to scroll to element or are you getting any exception?

Comment: I am able to scroll to element, same thing. It is clicking only when I move mouse over the element manually.

Comment: Any help Please

Comment: seems like only after you mouse hover on some element click listener is enabled. could you share the html code

Comment: Yes, but I could not share the code as it is strictly prohibited. Is the way I am writing the xpath is correct. Please help.

Comment: It is working now, class name is changing on mouse hover, then changed to new classname.